# href for a list with a background image in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am displaying images inside a div 
This is the html rendered by jquery

```
<div id="flickrSlider" class="flickrSliderHolder" style="width: 500px; height: 345px;">
<span class="caption"></span>
<ul style="width: 1000px; height: 320px; left: 0px;">
    <li style="background-image: url('example.jpg'); width: 500px;"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('example2.jpg'); width: 500px;"></li>
</ul>
```

I want a href tag for each image to link to google.com like this

```
<div id="flickrSlider" class="flickrSliderHolder" style="width: 500px; height: 345px;">
<span class="caption"></span>
<ul style="width: 1000px; height: 320px; left: 0px;">
    <a href="www.google.com"> <li style="background-image: url('example.jpg'); width: 500px;"></a></li>
     <li style="background-image: url('example2.jpg'); width: 500px;"></li>
</ul>
```

How can I code it in JQuery? 
I tried

```
var arrowLink = $('<a>',{
                            className: 'link',
                            href: 'www.google.com',

        }).appendTo(li);
```

but it is

but it is rendered like

```
<div id="flickrSlider" class="flickrSliderHolder" style="width: 500px; height: 345px;">
<span class="caption"></span>
<ul style="width: 1000px; height: 320px; left: 0px;">
    <li style="background-image: url('example.jpg'); width: 500px;"><a href="www.google.com"></a></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('example2.jpg'); width: 500px;"></li>
</ul>
```

Pls.help

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping a `<li>` in a `<a>` is not valid xhtml, which is why jQuery is putting the `<a>` inside the `<li>` (which is valid).

Style `li > a` to match the width + height of the `<li>` and you should get the desired result.

Comment: I matched the height and width, but still it doesn't go anywhere when I click on it and I dont see the link

Answer (score 0):

you are using a background image thus there is nothing to click on.

**Edit**: @adam's edited answer to match the height and width will fix that

Answer (score 0):

You should style `li > a` with `display:block` so it assumes the height and width of its parent element.